# Darknet esta dando tanta salida que la página web alcanza los límites de memoria

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colab

estoy entrenando un modelo con yolo darknet en google colab pero al comenzar el entrenamiento la pagina se queda congelada.
quisiera saber si alguno de ustedes sabe a que se refiere o conocen otra solución a mi problema. Gracias

Aqui esta mi codigo:

```
    !unzip "/content/drive/My Drive/custom_dib_model/darknet.zip"
    
    !./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights data/person.jpg
    !ln -s /content/drive/'My Drive'/dib_weights/backup /content/darknet
    !./darknet detector train dibujos_dataset/dib.data dib_yolov4.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -map -dont_show
```

en la primera linea descomprimo la carpeta de darknet
,en la segunda line pruebo el detector con la imagen de una persona para saber que funciona bien el darknet
,en la tercera linea creo un backup para guardar los datos del entrenamiento
,en la cuarta linea entreno mi dataset usando la configuracion dib_yolov4.cfg
todos los pesos se van guardando en google drive

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda que es demasiado importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

solucione el problema modificando el archivo de configuracion `dib_yolo.cfg` cambiado las subdivisiones de 64 a 16.